# React Router - Nested Components will not Render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a standard react component created with `create-react-app`. I am trying to render different components using `Link`s.

Here is my `App.js`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Router, Route, browserHistory } from 'react-router'
import Header from './Header';
import One from './One';
import Two from './Two';
import Three from './Three';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Router history={browserHistory} >
          <Route component={Header} path="/" >
            <Route component={One} path="one" name="One" />
            <Route component={Two} path="two" name="Two" />
            <Route component={Three} path="three" name="Three" />
          </Route>
        </Router>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Here is the `Header.js`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router'
import './App.css';

class Header extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
    };

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ul>
        <li><Link to="/">Home</Link></li>
        <li><Link to="/one">One</Link></li>
        <li><Link to="/two">Two</Link></li>
        <li><Link to="/three">Three</Link></li>
      </ul>
    );
  }
}

export default Header;
```

Here is `One.js`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
    };

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <h1>One</h1>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

I click on one of the links, the address bar changes, but no components will render inside of the nested route. I can remove the nesting:

```
<Router history={browserHistory} >
  <Route component={Header} path="/" />
  <Route component={One} path="one" name="One" />
  <Route component={Two} path="two" name="Two" />
  <Route component={Three} path="three" name="Three" />
</Router>
```

Which will render the components but the Header is no longer rendered.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot this part in Header component:

```
this.props.children
```

You need to define the place where you want to `render` your child components, Use this:

```
render() {
    return (
     <div>
        <ul>
           <li><Link to="/">Home</Link></li>
           <li><Link to="/one">One</Link></li>
           <li><Link to="/two">Two</Link></li>
           <li><Link to="/three">Three</Link></li>
        </ul>
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    );
  }
```